# Can't unscrew popup bathtub drain

Tags: plumbing, drain, bathtub

[Bathroom drain has a pop-up drain.](https://imgur.com/a/3aWsSxy)

I've tried rotating counter clockwise, clockwise, popped up/down.  Everything short of a crowbar.
I either need to replace it or adjust it so it actually blocks the water (so we can put kids in the bath.)

Yes, totally trying to avoid hiring a plumber.
Questions/thoughts/advice?

Comment: The pop-up I installed in our lavatory unscrews CCW. Get a strap wrench and  try more force.

Comment: Do you plan to replace the rubber seal?

Comment: A second wrench to hold the bottom in place will not hurt.  Might not be needed, but twisting the bottom is not good.

Comment: With many pop-ups, the chrome cap pops off to reveal a large slotted screw, which can be unscrewed.